# How to view xcode log file on Windows?

Tags: ios, api, logging

I'm a Microsoft developer who has written a Web API (using .NET) for a multi-platform mobile project (native versions to be written for iPhone, Android, and Windows).

The backend is in SQL Server, and the idea is that the mobile apps will make calls to the API to retrieve/update data. I have tested the API and believe it is fit for purpose.

The iOS developer (located in India) is adamant that the API is slow, unstable and causing errors. We're currently in a bit of a deadlock about the issue and not making much progress.

He hasn't asked for anything specific to be changed, only general complaints about slowness/instability, which he says is causing the iPhone app to crash.

However after some time, he's sent through what he says is an xcode log file which contains errors. Is there any easy way I can view this log file on a Windows computer?

[Screen capture in Notepad++](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qF0CU.png)

Comment: Using notepad++?It is just a file,you just need a file editer

Comment: Notepad was the first thing I tried. The contents of the file are binary. He says it's an xcode log file, i'm not an iOS developer, I have no way to verify if it actually is one. But it's certainly not a text file. Any ideas?